# opengl release memory after calling glBufferData causes the data not to display

Tags: c++, opengl, memory-management

I am drawing in opengl using indexed drawing. I am sending the vertices & the indexes to the graphic card, and then trying to release the local buffers.
Releasing the vertices buffer - no problem, but if I release the index buffer, nothing is displayed.

putting it simply, this code works:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &m_VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_Vertices.size()*6*sizeof(float), m_Vertices.data(),GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

m_Vertices.clear();
m_Vertices.shrink_to_fit();

glGenBuffers(1, &m_IBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_IBO);   
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_TriangleIndeces.size() * sizeof(GLsizei), m_TriangleIndeces.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW); 

//  m_TriangleIndeces.clear();
//  m_TriangleIndeces.shrink_to_fit();
```

but if I un-remark the last 2 lines - nothing is displayed.

I also tried to release the buffer after first rendering, but the same phenomena occured.

I understood that once the opengl buffers the data, if to the driver or to the graphic card, the local copy of it is free for me to abuse, so I am puzzled.

I am working on windows 10. The device manager says I have "AMD radeon (TM) R7 M360", and "Intel HD graphics 520", whatever that means.

Comment: Can you show the definitions of m_TriangleIndeces?

Comment: Maybe you are not using m_IBO for the actual drawing, but use the client side index array?

Comment: What type are you using for the indices? `GLsizei` definitely looks invalid. I don't think it should cause the problem you describe, but using `sizeof(GLsizei)` must be wrong.

Comment: "typedef int GLsizei;" is a definition found in glew.h

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the OpenGL implementation should indeed perform a copy of the data.

This could be a driver bug.
Since you seem have two GPUs, I assume you're running the application on your Intel GPU by default (Intel is famous for having bad GPU drivers). Did you try testing it on both GPUs? And are your GPU drivers up to date?

Comment: thank you for your response. Hoe do I forward my usage to a specific GPU?

Comment: In the driver settings. I don't have such a system, so I can't tell you for sure. Maybe this helps: https://support.serato.com/hc/en-us/articles/202305784-Changing-graphics-card-settings-to-use-your-dedicated-GPU-on-a-Windows-computer-
Also please answer my question regarding the GPU drivers.

Comment: Regarding the drives, AMD indeed needed to be updated, Intel driver was already up-to-date, but the update didn't do the trick... I'll look at the ling you sent